# Remove parent element on click with plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn stuff I was used to do in jQuery do in plain JavaScript.

I have example I found on the internet to solve and it really gave me hard time.

I am trying to remove parent `div.single` on click on `button.remove`.

Here is the code;

```js
 var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('remove')
    
 for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click',function (e) {      
      e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
    } , false);
 }
```

```html
 <div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X4</button>
  </div>
```

I am getting error `e.parentNode is undefined`.

Here is the jQuery code which does the same I am after.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {    
    $(this).parent('.single').remove()
  })
})
```

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You need `e.target.parentNode`. The `e` object is the event object, not a node. It is the `target` property that references the node.

Comment: replace `e` with `this` inside the method.

Comment: both solutions work, thank you guys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to get the element reference from the event object([currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)/[target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target))

Note: All the modern browser's have support for [Node.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('remove')

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();
    //this.closest('.single').remove() // in modern browsers in complex dom structure
    //this.parentNode.remove(); //this refers to the current target element 
    //e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X1</button>
</div>
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X2</button>
</div>
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X3</button>
</div>
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

To remove parent node as short way:

```html
<div class="single">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
   <button type="button" onclick="return this.parentNode.remove();" class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to say that I much prefer this as it works really well for dynamically created elements too. Imagine building a page that elements are dynamically added as opposed to the OP version where the elements are rendered on load, this would work best as it attaches itself to that specific element as a childnode. Gorgeous!

Comment: This answer is perfection! In my case, I was removing a grandparent node, so I did `this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [ES6 and above](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_from.asp), you could avoid having to use the `currentTarget` for the click event:

```js
const removeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

Array.from(removeButtons).forEach((removeButton) => {
  removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeButton.parentNode.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X1</button>
</div>
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X2</button>
</div>
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X3</button>
</div>
<div class="single">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <button type="button" class="remove">X4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this.parentElement.remove can also work

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Node List of the buttons in your html with class of "remove"
  const removeButtonsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".remove"); 

  // No Need to convert node list to an array, you can use use forEach to loop over a nodeList. Just beware it's not an array
  

  // Loop through the list and add an event listener, on click to run a function on each btn (button) in the array. The function removes the parent. But you can inspect the element of your html and you can play with in console if your html chnages to find the correct parent, you may have to get the parent of prarent of parent.
  removeButtonsNodeList.forEach((btn) => {

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      btn.parentElement.remove(); 
    });

  })
```

```html
<div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X1 - Delete Me</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X2 - Delete Me</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X3 - Delete Me</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="single">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    <button type="button" class="remove">X4 - Delete Me</button>
  </div>
```